# Storing values of 2 floats together then retrieving them together IOS Development

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

How would I go about doing this I have tried to store the floats in their own array and then assign them to a separate array when I retrieve them. What would be better then NSuserdefualts

```
 for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    NSString *keys = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%d", i];
    NSObject * object = [prefs objectForKey:keys];
    if(object != nil){
        NSLog(@"There is a a saved value for %@", keys);
    }else{

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:coords forKey:keys];
        NSLog(@"Saved value %f , %f ... in slot %@",key1, key2 ,keys);
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Your question/issue is unclear.

Comment: I want to know if NSUserDefualts is a bad choice for storing my data

Comment: 10 objects? Not a problem.

Comment: What are the types of `key1`, `key2` and `coords`?